# SQL Server 2017 Enterprise - how to fast update entire columns

Tags: sql-server

I need to update all values in one column in a table. The table is large - nearly 420 000 000 rows.  Is there any clever way to conduct this operation quickly and without causing a lot of transaction log growth?
I know I can do that in batches, but maybe some sort of metadata trick is possible? Some clever way to use ALTER TABLE SWITCH maybe?
TIA

Comment: What do you need to alter the values to?...can you please provide an example? E.g. if you wanted to NULL them all out, then dropping the column and re-adding it would be your best bet, but without more context on your Table schema, the data, and what you want to set it to, it's hard to give a specific answer.

Comment: Unfortunately they can't be NULLs. It's more of a data obfuscation scenario - say, I need to change real surnames to some generic string, like 'HIDDEN'.
And I know there's Dynamic Data Masking available, but this time business requirements are to really change the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maybe some sort of metadata trick is possible?

- Adding a new column with a default can be a metadata-only operation.
- Dropping a column can be a metadata-only operation.
- Renaming a column can be a metadata-only operation.

I'm not certian that all of these always are metadata-only for every type of table, but  try something like:

```
  use AdventureWorksDW2017
  go
  drop table if exists DimCustomer2 
  go
  select c.*
  into DimCustomer2
  from DimCustomer c
  cross join (select top 100 * from sys.messages) d
  go
  set statistics io on
  go
  begin transaction
  alter table DimCustomer2 add LastName2 nvarchar(200) not null default 'HIDDEN'
  alter table DimCustomer2 drop column LastName
  exec sp_rename 'Dbo.DimCustomer2.LastName2', 'LastName', 'COLUMN'
  commit
  go
  set statistics io off
  go
  select top 100 * 
  from DimCustomer2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Works flawlessly :) Thank you very much